# Does $x \circ y = id_V$ with $x \in GL(V)$ and $y \in L(V)$ implies $y \in GL(V)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

Let $V$ be a real Banach space. Denote by $L(V)$ the real Banach space of linear continuous applications from $V$ to $V$ and by $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ the set of all linear bijective bicontinue applications from $V$ to $V$.

Let $x \in \mathrm{GL}(V)$ and $y \in L(V)$. Does $x \circ y = id_V$ implies $y \in \mathrm{GL}(V)$ ? Does $y \circ x = id_V$ implies $y \in \mathrm{GL}(V)$ ?

For the context, the question above arise when I try to apply implicit function theorem to prove $f \in \mathrm{GL}(V) \mapsto f^{-1} \in \mathrm{GL}(V)$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$. Since I already know one way to prove this $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$, so this question is not about how to prove this $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$.

Comment: Both $x \circ y = \operatorname{id}_V$ and $y \circ x = \operatorname{id}_V $ gives us that $y=x^{-1} \in \operatorname{GL}(V)$ (just compose each equation by $x^{-1}$ on the appropiate side).

Comment: @azif00 Ok. I mistakenly wanted to use open mapping theorem, now I see it obviously complicates things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\in GL(V)$, then $x\circ y=\text{id}_V$ implies $y=x^{-1}$ (and $x^{-1}$ is also trivially an element of $GL(V)$), so yes $y\in GL(V)$.

Comment: If on the other hand all you know is $x\in L(V)$, then you in general can't make this conclusion (you can make it if $V$ is finite-dimensional).

Comment: Note the linear algebraic setting is a red herring here; in set theoretic terms, a right inverse of a bijection is a bijection, and a left inverse of a bijection is a bijection. For any associative operation $\circ$ with identity, it is a standard fact that if $x \circ y = \text{id}$ and $z \circ x = \text{id}$, then $z=y$ is the unique inverse of $x$.